# Null ResultSet and how to fill it

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, arraylist

I have the next code:

```
ResultSet rs= null; 
TipoEstablecimientoHotel tipoEstablecimiento = new TipoEstablecimientoHotel(rs);
```

Of course, the second line goes into a null pointer exception, so I want to initialize tha "rs", but I don't want the data coming from a database at this point. I'm lost with it.

Comment: So what do you want to have in this phase? Why do you receive rs as a parameter to the constructor?

Comment: Well, perhaps I could substitute that rs, but not in the constructor, but here. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, I've resolved it. I was declaring TipoEstablecimientoHotel(rs). I simply override the class and made one call to TipoEstablecimientoHotel(). Son the new code is: TipoEstablecimientoHotel tipoEstablecimiento = new TipoEstablecimientoHotel();

Answer (score 3):

We have no idea what `TipoEstablecimientoHotel` does, or why it needs a result set. If it needs it at the point of construction then *either* you need to defer constructing `TipoEstablecimientoHotel` until you've got the results, *or* you need to redesign it so you can give it the data later.

Basically, a problem like this should be taken as a suggestion to take a step back and consider your design - think about what *should* need data when, and adjust the design to meet those needs.

Comment: Agreed. Does `TipoEstablecimientoHotel` need a `ResultSet` or the data contained within? If it's the latter, extract the data first. Otherwise you'll code a dependancy to a database in your class, which I assume is a domain class used by your business logic.

Comment: Right, it is. The fact is I need to get that rs with data. What I really need is not to have that value null, but I still don't have data to fill in that rs.

Comment: @elvenbyte: So you need the data, but you don't *have* the data. As I said, this indicates that you've got a design problem.

Comment: @elvenbyte: Well we can't help you with those really - we don't know nearly enough context.

Comment: You have the answer in a comment at the question itself.